# Using Google Maps Api and external Json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to pull a list of locations from an external json file, titled "locations.json" and create individual markers for each item. Having trouble actually parsing the file using ajax.

```
[
 {
"latitude": 38.558961, 
"longitude": -121.423011,
"name": "Library",
"title": "THIS IS WHERE STUFF GETS DONE!"
  },
{
"latitude": 38.562605, 
"longitude": -121.419683,
"name": "Bridge",
"title": "Water below"
},
{
"latitude": 38.556652, 
"longitude": -121.423842,
"name": "GYM",
"title": "WORKOUT"
},
{
"latitude": 38.555465, 
"longitude": -121.422551,
"name": "Stadium",
"title": "FOOTBALL!"
}

]
```

Here is the code in the javascript file.

```
$.getJSON("csus_locations.txt", function(json1) {    $.each(json1, function(key, data) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude); 
    // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        title: data.name
    });
});
});
```

Another solution tried was the following, using an ajax method and a for loop:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/locations",
type: 'POST',
//force to handle it as text
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {

//data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
 //and pass downloaded data
 var json = $.parseJSON(data);

}
});
}); 

for (var i = 0; i < csus_locations.length; i++) {
var tourStop = locations[i];
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(tourStop[0], tourStop[1]);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    shadow: shadow,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
    name: tourStop[2],
});
```

Comment: Both solutions seem to be defining a marker variable within a loop and then overwriting that marker variable with new info on each iteration of the loop.  Are you only seeing one marker on your map?  I would suggest reviewing this, seems exactly like what you want to do.  http://en.marnoto.com/2013/12/mapa-com-varios-marcadores-google-maps.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load local file using file URI scheme, e.g. `file:///home/app/csus_locations.txt`, in Google Chrome browser? It is not allowed by default due to security reason ([details](http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/)).

You could use flag in Google Chrome browser:

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

to allow load of local files.

If it is not the case, then since it is JSON file type, try to explicitly specify `dataType: "json"`, for example:

```
function loadMarkers(map)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "csus_locations.txt",
        cache: false,   
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

            $.each(data, function(key, item) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude); 
                // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latLng,
                  map: map,
                  title: item.name
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cXJAl3go36LZikWIqjuY?p=preview)

or specify `format: "json"` for [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), for example:

```
function loadMarkers(map)
{
    $.getJSON("csus_locations.txt",
    {
       format: "json"
    })
    .done(function(json) {    
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {
           var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude); 
           // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latLng,
              map: map,
              title: data.name
           });
           console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AN6OgDKHrBG8LWZmHOHF)